# (java) Superclass s = new childClass

Tags: java

Parent class:

```
public class superClass {

    private void m1() {
        System.out.println("SuperClass's m1()");
    }

    public void m2() {
        System.out.println("SuperClass's m2()");
        m1();
    }
}
```

Child class:

```
public class Modify extends superClass {

    public void m1() {
        System.out.println("Modify's method1");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        superClass s = new Modify();
        s.m2();
    }
}
```

When would I use :

```
superClass s = new Modify();
```

instead of:

```
Modify s = new Modify();
```

Is it possible to declare s as a superClass on the left side but calling 'new Modify()' on the right side? 
Shouldn't we only able to call 'new Modify()' if we declare s as a Modify class?

Comment: you could run and check the behavior :)

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to declare s as a superClass on the left side but
>   calling 'new Modify()' on the right side?

Yes, It's possible, It's called as Polymorphic behaviour in Java

> Shouldn't we only able to call 'new Modify()' if we declare s as a
>   Modify class?

Since `Modify` is a subclass of a `superClass`, it inherits all superclass public methods. So, It perfectly ok to call the super class public methods, since all public methods are inherited by subclass. This is called Inheritance in Java.

Read more about [Polymorphism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html) and [Inheritance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html), then you will understand he usage

Comment: When would I use them?

Answer (score 0):

Its a kind of polymorphism SuperClass reference to subclass object.

**Why would you do that?**

```
Super s = new Child();
```

from s you can call all methods of super because it is pointed to a child and child `is-a` super and also you can use methods of child that are overridden.